# How to transfer recycle bin to new computer

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I am currently running in Windows 10. I'm getting a new computer running Windows 11. I'd like to continue to have access to my current recycle bin on the new computer. Is there a way to transfer the contents of the recycle bin on this computer to the new one? This could have one of two outcomes:

- Ideally, I'd like the contents of the recycle bin on this computer to become the initial contents of the recycle bin on the new computer.
- If that's not possible, I'd like to at least copy the contents of the current recycle bin to a folder on the new computer to keep there until I'm comfortable that I won't need any of those deleted files. But if it's done this way, then I also need a log of each file's date deleted so I can sort it by that.

Comment: Don't use Recycle/Trash as a temporary storage area. That's not what it's for.

Comment: That's exactly what it's for. It's for temporary storage of deleted files in case I realize later that I shouldn't have deleted it.

Comment: You should not use Recycle Bin as a storage folder. It was not designed for that.

Comment: Yeah… but no. Windows has instilled that into users as a 'get out of jail free' card for so long that they think it's infallible. It's not. Don't use it as temporary storage. If you need a 'purgatory' then set one up & monitor it yourself.

Comment: Of course it's not infallible. But since I am also not infallible, it's helpful when it works.

Comment: That's what we have backups for. You're trying to push a structure into something it was never intended for, then wondering why it's not set up to migrate easily.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/mt1006/RecycleBinExporter It not only copies Recycle Bin files to a single directory but also creates a CSV file listing all applicable properties

Comment: @patkim - That's very interesting, and it could be what I need. I don't have Python, but I looked at the code (https://github.com/mt1006/RecycleBinExporter/blob/main/rbexp.py). It's getting the recycled bin data from `winshell.recycle_bin()`. I tried accessing that in PowerShell, but it doesn't exist there. Do you know what this object is in Windows that Python knows as `winshell.recycle_bin()`?

Comment: I am not an expert in Python but I think it's a Python module may be. I installed Python in VM, I also installed the two additional modules needed (pypiwin32 & winshell) and tested it and it worked. All files in Recycle Bin were copied to the folder from where the script was run and a .CSV was created providing info about file name/location/dates etc. After you install Python and put it in PATH the .py file will run seamlessly as a Python script and do its job.

Comment: I think I found Window's object: `$shell.Namespace(ssfBITBUCKET)` = `$shell.Namespace(10)`. Once that's assigned to a variable, the list of files and some properties is in `$var.Items()` and more properties are in `$var.GetDetailsOf($var.Items().Item(n), m)`, where `n` runs over the number of objects in the bin and `m` runs over the properties. It looks like the lowest `m`s are column numbers in the display of the bin, and then more data are at higher `m`s. Pretty tricky way for Windows to hide the data. It looks like Python's `winshell.recycle_bin()` is a structure derived from that.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that although it might not be a good **storage** practice, there are still valid cases in which one might need to obtain access to the Recycle Bin on an HDD/SSD that has an OS install that's tied to another work station.

Comment: You may be infallible, but it won't protect you from hardware failures, malware attacks and accidental modification of files. You need a proper backup. Solve that issue and the recycle bin problem will be nonexistent.

Answer (score 4):

> If that's not possible, I'd like to at least copy the contents of the
> current recycle bin to a folder on the new computer to keep there
> until I'm comfortable that I won't need any of those deleted files.
> But if it's done this way, then I also need a log of each file's date
> deleted so I can sort it by that.

After testing the script as written by GitHub user mt1006 I am posting this as an answer.

The project is `RecycleBinExporter` at GitHub repository https://github.com/mt1006/RecycleBinExporter

- Download and install Python 3.1 or above from https://www.python.org/downloads/
- During installation select the option to add it to PATH
- After installation open Command Prompt as admin and run the following commands

  py -m pip install pypiwin32

  py -m pip install winshell

This installs additional modules. Active Internet connection is needed here.

- Create a folder say C:\Recycle
- Download the Python script  https://github.com/mt1006/RecycleBinExporter/blob/main/rbexp.py
- Save it as say `export.py` at C:\Recycle
- Open Command Prompt as Admin and go to C:\Recycle
- Run the script export.py

[image]

[image]

[image]

- The script will export all files from Recycle Bin to a subfolder named `recycle_bin` in the folder from where it is run and will also create a .CSV file recording File Name, Original Location, Date Created and Date Deleted.
- You can then open the .CSV file in your preferred app.
- The script also handles duplicate file names. It appends `copy` in file name during export.

[image]

- Review the exported Recycle Bin files with help of the .CSV to decide what you want to keep and what to delete on new PC. You may even write a script to automate moving files to their original location by reading the contents of CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Restore the items in the recycle bin to a folder on the current computer. Files will generally go to their original source.

Then copy to a new computer.

This works here.

> The recycle bin has thousands of files. If I restore them all, then
> I'd have to go back to their original locations on the new computer
> and delete them all over again.

If that is the case and you are going to delete anyway, then sort the folder by name or other good sort and highlight / delete what you do not want prior to restoring to original location.

Comment: The recycle bin has thousands of files. If I restore them all, then I'd have to go back to their original locations on the new computer and delete them all over again. I could automate that process if I can get a log of those original locations. Can you add to your answer how to get that, along with each file's date deleted?

Comment: I did add to my answer .   You do need to organize so you can safely delete.

Comment: I don't understand what you've added, but it doesn't sound like something that could be automated for thousands of files in thousands of folders.

Comment: I am not sure how you might automate the process.  I find sorting files into logical groups normally facilitates management.

Comment: Anecdotally , people use Recycle bin and Outlook Deleted folders to save things. Not a good practice. As Tetsujin notes, set up your own folders. I do this all the time:   Documents for 2022  and Documents for 2022 to be deleted. Organize as you go.

Comment: Note that, for reasons unknown to me, Microsoft had at some point removed "modified date" from the default sorting categories; however, you can re-add it back via context menu.  This should help with recently modified files, which in this case, should apply to deleted/restored files (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not at a Windows PC to verify at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

According to my tests, it's possible to use The Recycle Bin viewer
(which is actually just Explorer) to both drag files out-of and
into the Recycle Bin.

Dragging a file into the Recycle Bin has the effect of setting it
with the same restore folder as the one it originated from.
This means that dragging a file outside of the Recycle Bin will lose
the original restore folder.

If you don't care about the original restore folder, you could on the old
computer select the entire Recycle Bin and drag its whole contents
to a portable disk that you can move over to the new computer.

Although you can copy the moved files into the Recycle Bin of the new
computer, it would be safer to keep them in a regular folder.
The Recycle Bin may sometimes be emptied by Windows as a side-effect
of using some utilities.